# How do I access int variables from a method in another class?

Tags: java, file, class, methods, integer

I have a method (public void AddBusses) in a class called Bus. There are int variables that keep track of the size of some ArrayLists in the method. I want to be able to use the arraylist size in my main class.

I tried declaring the int variables in Class Bus before the method, but this just made them all 0 and would not give their values in the method.

I then tries to make get methods to get them to the main class, but this had the same outcome with it returning 0's.

The attempts discussed above are located in the Bus class and are commented out.
Below are the int variable in question- in b1, b2, b3

```
//      public int b1;
//      public int b2;
//      public int b3;
//      public int b4;
        
//      public int getB1(){
//          return b1;          
//      }
//      public int getB2(){
//          return b2;
//      }
//      public int getB3(){
//          return b3;
//      }
```

here is the relevant code in the main class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;//Includes ArrayList

public class Bussin 
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
        
        //Instantiate 3 ArrayLists 
        
        //ArrayList<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        List<Student> StudentList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Student>());
        //ArrayList<Bus> Bus = new ArrayList<Bus> ();
        List<Bus> BusList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Bus>());
        List<Bus2> BusList2 = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Bus2>());
        //ArrayList<BusStop> BusStop = new ArrayList<BusStop>();
        List<BusStop> BusStopList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<BusStop>());

File myFile_1_5 = null;
        FileWriter myWriter_1_5 = null;
        Scanner myReader_1_5 = null;

//1_5
        try {
              myFile_1_5 = new File("D:\\11th Grade Portfolio\\AP Computer Science A\\ArrayListSizes.txt");          
              if (myFile_1_5.createNewFile()) 
              {
                System.out.println("File created: " + myFile_1_5.getName());
              } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
                myReader_1_5 = new Scanner(myFile_1_5); 
                  int ReadStudentListSize_1_5 = myReader_1_5.nextInt();
                  int ReadBusListSize_1_5 = myReader_1_5.nextInt();
                  int ReadBusStopListSize_1_5 = myReader_1_5.nextInt();
                  System.out.println(ReadStudentListSize_1_5);
                  System.out.println(ReadBusListSize_1_5);
                  System.out.println(ReadBusStopListSize_1_5);            
                      myReader_1_5.close();           
              }   
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred.");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        

        case 2:
                
                Scanner Reader2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int R2 = 0;
                while(R2 != -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nBusses");
                    System.out.println("1. Add Busses\n2. Remove Busses\n3. Move Busses\n4. View Busses\n5. View Students\n6. See all Busses");
                    System.out.println("\n Enter 1-3 to make a selection, or -1 to quit:");
                    R2 = Reader2.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("__________________________________________________________________\n");
                    
                    Bus b = new Bus (BusList);  
                    switch (R2)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            System.out.println("Returning to main menu...");
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            
                            b.AddBusses(StudentList, BusList2, BusStopList);
                            
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            
                            b.RemoveBusses();
                            
                            break;
                        case 3: 
                            
                            b.MoveBusses();
                            
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            
                            b.ViewBusses();
                            
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            
                            b.ViewStudents();
                            
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            
//                          b.SeeAllBusses();                           
                            System.out.println("______________");
                            System.out.println("See all Busses");                                                       
//    Test                      int StudentListSize = b.b5;
//        with                  int BusListSize = b.b6;
//          b5,6,7.             int BusStopListSize = b.b7;
//      This                    int StudentListSize = b.getB1();
//          was the             int BusListSize = b.getB1();
//              second attempt.     int BusStopListSize = b.getB3();    
//      This                    int StudentListSize = b.b1;  
//        was the               int BusListSize = b.b2;
//               first attempt.         int BusStopListSize = b.b3;     
                            
                            try {                               
                            myWriter_1_5 = new FileWriter("D:\\11th Grade Portfolio\\AP Computer Science A\\ArrayListSizes.txt");
                            
                            myWriter_1_5.write(StudentListSize + "\n");//+ " " + BusListSize + " " + BusStopListSize);
                            myWriter_1_5.write(BusListSize + "\n");
                            myWriter_1_5.write(BusStopListSize + "\n");
                            
                            
                            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
                            
                            myWriter_1_5.close();
                            
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            
                            //Read from the file
                            try {
                                
                                  myReader_1_5 = new Scanner(myFile_1_5);
                                  while (myReader_1_5.hasNextLine()) 
                                  {
                                    String data1_5 = myReader_1_5.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println(data1_5);
                                  }                                   
                                  myReader_1_5.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                  
                                }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  
                                                                                      try {
                            myWriter_2 = new FileWriter("D:\\11th Grade Portfolio\\AP Computer Science A\\Busses.txt");
                            
                                ListIterator<Student> l = StudentList.listIterator();
                                while(l.hasNext())
                                {
                                    myWriter_2.write(l.next().toString().toUpperCase()) ;       
                                }
                                
                                myWriter_2.write("\n");
                                
                                ListIterator<Bus2> m = BusList2.listIterator();
                                while(m.hasNext())
                                {
                                    myWriter_2.write(m.next().toString().toUpperCase()); 
                                }
                                
                                myWriter_2.write("\n");
                                
                                ListIterator<BusStop> n = BusStopList.listIterator();
                                while(n.hasNext())
                                {
                                    myWriter_2.write(n.next().toString().toUpperCase());
                                }
                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                            System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
                            
                            myWriter_2.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            
                            //Read from the file
                            try {
                                
                                  myReader_2 = new Scanner(myFile_2);
                                  while (myReader_2.hasNextLine()) 
                                  {
                                    String data = myReader_2.nextLine();
                                    System.out.println(data);
                                  }                                   
                                  myReader_2.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                              System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                  
                                }
                            
                            
                            
                            break;
}
}
```

I forgot to mention that most of the code in the main class is part of a nested menu, so I didn't include the start of the big menu but you can see one of the nested menus in the code above.

Below is the relevant code from the Bus Class:
(sry ik this a lot- im confused myself :( )

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Bus 
{
    
    
    //public String Bus;
    public List<Bus2> Bus_B;
    public List<Student> StudentList_B;
    public List<BusStop> BusStopList_B;
    
    //public Bus(List<Student> StudentList2, String Bus2, List<BusStop> BusStopList2)
    public Bus(List<Student> StudentList2, List<Bus2> BusList3, List<BusStop> BusStopList2)
    {
        
        StudentList_B = StudentList2;
        //Bus = Bus2;
        Bus_B = BusList3;
        BusStopList_B = BusStopList2;
    }
    

    //Stuff for all methods to use
    
        static Scanner Reader_B = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        private List<Bus> BusList;
        
        Bus(List<Bus> BusList)
        {
            this.BusList = BusList;
        }
        
//      public int b1;
//      public int b2;
//      public int b3;
//      public int b4;
        
//      public int getB1()
//      {
//          return b1;
//          
//      }
//      public int getB2()
//      {
//          return b2;
//          
//      }
//      public int getB3()
//      {
//          return b3;
//      }
        
        
        public int b5 = 69; // b5,6,& 7 were just tests to access the ints- these worked and 
        public int b6 = 420; // was able to access the value, but only b/c I initialized  
        public int b7 = 911; // the method.
        
        public void AddBusses (List<Student> StudentList2, List<Bus2> BusList3, List<BusStop> BusStopList2)
        {
            String Bus2;
            String Name2;
            String BusStop2;
            
            int StudentCount;
            int BusStopCount;
                    
            System.out.println("__________");
            System.out.println("Add Busses");
            
            
            System.out.println("Enter the number of the new Bus:");         
            Bus2 = Reader_B.nextLine();         
            
            Bus2 NewBus_B = new Bus2 (Bus2);
            
            BusList3.add(NewBus_B);
            
             int b2 = BusList3.size();
            
            System.out.println("The size of the array is " + b2 + ". The bus number is " + NewBus_B.Bus + ".");
            
            System.out.println("How many students ride Bus " + Bus2 + "?");         
            StudentCount = Reader_B.nextInt();          
            System.out.println("Enter the names of the " + StudentCount + " Students that ride Bus " + Bus2 + ".");
            
            Name2 = Reader_B.nextLine();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < StudentCount; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Student Name:");
                Name2 = Reader_B.nextLine();
                
                Student NewStudent_B = new Student(Name2, Bus2);
                
                StudentList2.add(NewStudent_B); 
                
                int b1 = StudentList2.size();
                
                System.out.println("the size of the array is " + b1 + ". The student's name is " + NewStudent_B.Name + " and their bus number is " + NewStudent_B.BusNumber + ".");
                
            }
                    
            System.out.println("\nHow many Bus Stops does " + Bus2 + " stop at?");          
            BusStopCount = Reader_B.nextInt();          
            System.out.println("Enter the names of the " + BusStopCount + " Bus Stops that Bus " + Bus2 + " stops at.");
            
            BusStop2 = Reader_B.nextLine();
            
            for (int j = 0; j < BusStopCount; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("Bus Stop Name:");
                
                BusStop2 = Reader_B.nextLine();
                
                BusStop NewBusStop_B = new BusStop(BusStop2, Bus2);
                
                BusStopList2.add(NewBusStop_B);
                
                int b3 = BusStopList2.size();
                
                System.out.println("The size of the array is " + b3 + ". The name of the new Bus Stop is " + NewBusStop_B.BusStop + ".");
            }
            
            
            
            Bus NewBus = new Bus(StudentList2, BusList3, BusStopList2);
            
            BusList.add(NewBus);
        
            int b4 = BusList.size();
            
            System.out.println("The size of the array is " + b4 + ".");
                    
            
            
            
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and decrease the amount of code to make your question more readable.

Comment: The int variables b1, b2, and b3 are initialized in the AddBusses method in Class Bus. They hold the sizes of the 3 lists. I want to be able to access and use those numbers in the main class for something else. @RandomLonelyDev

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue!

In the Bus class, I declared my int variables outside the method as *public static int*, then removed the declaration statement from the method.

In the Main class, I accessed the variables with a call to the class, and then the variables.

Example of old and new code below:

Relevant Main class code:
Before (2 different ways):

```
//                          int StudentListSize = b.b1;
//                          int BusListSize = b.b2;
//                          int BusStopListSize = b.b3;
//                          int StudentListSize = b.getB1();
//                          int BusListSize = b.getB1();
//                          int BusStopListSize = b.getB3();
```

After:

```
                        int StudentListSize = Bus.b1;
                        int BusListSize = Bus.b2;
                        int BusStopListSize = Bus.b3;
```

Relevant Bus Class code:
Before (2 different attempts):

```
//      public int b1;
//      public int b2;
//      public int b3;
//      public int b4;
        
//      public int getB1()
//      {
//          return b1;
//          
//      }
//      public int getB2()
//      {
//          return b2;
//          
//      }
//      public int getB3()
//      {
//          return b3;
//      }
```

Inside method:

```
//          int b1 = StudentList2.size();
//          int b2 = BusList3.size();
//          int b3 = BusStopList2.size();
```

After:

```
public static int b1;
public static int b2;
public static int b3;
```

Inside method:

```
b1 = StudentList2.size();
b2 = BusList3.size();
b3 = BusStopList2.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen in your code, you never assign a value to b1, 2, 3, or 4 accept from within a method.  If you run the method AddBusses() you b1 should become a valid value.